# What is the recommended way for handling NTP?

Tags: time

In my answer to [How do I setup Tor on Debian for secure use as a SOCKS5 proxy?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/how-do-i-setup-tor-on-debian-for-secure-use-as-a-socks5-proxy), I don't force traffic to port 123 (NTP) to use Tor. Being UDP, I don't get how I can.

Is there an "NTP port" for Tor? I don't see anything in the manual.

What is the recommended way for handling NTP?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is using [tlsdate](https://github.com/ioerror/tlsdate/). This software connects to some TLS servers and extracts the time from the handshake. tlsdate uses TCP, so it can be used with Tor. As far as I know ChromeOS uses tlsdate to securely retrieve time data.

Comment: Tails does not use tlsdate. See [Time syncing design document](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Time_syncing/)

Comment: @Lunar Could you perhaps make that an answer? Once I understand and test, I could also do that.

Comment: @Lunar OK, that seems pretty straightforward. There's a custom HTP, and a Network Manager script. Once I test, would you prefer that I quote rather than paraphrase?

Comment: @mirmir Do what feels appropriate. :) Don't forget to talk to Tails folks if you work on extracting their htpdate system. I guess other distributions might be interested in re-using them.

Comment: I forgot about this. Upon reflection, I'm dubious about relying on HTTP/S headers for time. So is there no way to poll any NTP servers?

Comment: Also see https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8170 and related tickets.